# Automa api running with Python 2.7.6 is hanging my Windows Desktop system

Tags: python, wpf, windows, user-interface

**My Requirement:**
 
I have a WPF application that generates a GUI binary - which I am suppose to test.

**What's happening:**
After successfully installing Automa, and integrated it with Python 2.7.6v - I was able to test my application through Automa alone. It works fine: it doesn't crash/hangs my system regardless of what I do.
Now that I am running the Automa api with Python. While I am running the script, sometimes it is able to run successfully. But when I close the idle during the script running or any abnormal operation happens during the script running. It just freezes my system. The CPU Usage is around 1-2% only and I cannot do anything on my system but to restart it.

### What should I do ?

*My System:*
Windows 7  32-bit OS, Intel Core 2 Duo CPU, 3GB RAM, DELL Optiplex 380.

Comment: Ok... I resolved the issue myself. The system variables did not tally with the user variables.

Comment: In your OP you may want to add your code (e.g., read http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). To give back to the community, you may want to post the code that works as an answer below.